# I want to use session variable to hide display elements in angular js

Tags: angularjs, session-variables

I want to use the session variable **logged** to hide and display my angular elements
I set the value of this element to true in java code.

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("logged", "true");
```

I tried the following code

```
<div ng-show = "${logged}">
```

but the div is not displayed till I make refresh (F5) to my page
**EDIT**: I am using spring security with angularjs

Comment: So these are server-side sessions?

Comment: ok how can I fix this problem (I am new with web applciation development)

Comment: please provide more information on, how your application work,server side code and client side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the proper way required that you should use cookies and localstorage for client side scripting.
as the cookies and localstorage have userdefined expiry time.